# Navigation Menu Not Displaying in orchard 1.6

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I created a new theme in orchard 1.6 using codegen. After I created the theme I added the navigation part in the `Layout.cshtml` like so:

```
@if (Model.Navigation != null) {

    @Zone(Model.Navigation)
}
```

But the navigation menu is not displaying. I am new to orchard, so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu is a widget. Go to the widget management screen and add it to your navigation zone.